# Issues regarding classification instead of regression using deep learning

Tags: classification, deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

I have a question. I have a network which works fine I want to do the regression. However, when I am trying to use it for classification(after maing supposedly appropriate changes) I am facing some issues. I have 9 classes, but the issue is that the network is outputting me in a way that is not clear to me. It outputs me a 9x1 vector for each object which is fine but the values inside are not probabilities. I have tried converting the softmax output to probabilities(exp(1)/(exp(1)+..+exp(n))) but to no affect . I am using caffe an matcaffe 
. What I want is given the input the network tells me to which class it belongs. Basically in the output I want a single value which represents my class. I am attaching my prototxt file.`

```
name: "Zeiler_conv5"

input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224

input: "rois"
input_dim: 1 # to be changed on-the-fly to num ROIs
input_dim: 5 # [batch ind, x1, y1, x2, y2] zero-based indexing
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1

input: "labels"
input_dim: 1 # to be changed on-the-fly to match num ROIs
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1

input: "bbox_targets"
input_dim: 1  # to be changed on-the-fly to match num ROIs
input_dim: 84 # 4 * (K+1) (=21) classes
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1

input: "bbox_loss_weights"
input_dim: 1  # to be changed on-the-fly to match num ROIs
input_dim: 84 # 4 * (K+1) (=21) classes
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1

input: "angle_head"
input_dim: 1  # to be changed on-the-fly to match num ROIs
input_dim: 9 # 9 (-180:45:180) classes
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1

input: "angle_head_weight"
input_dim: 1  # to be changed on-the-fly to match num ROIs
input_dim: 9 # 9 (-180:45:180) classes
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1


layer {
    name: "conv1"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "data"
    top: "conv1"
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 96
        kernel_size: 7
        pad: 3
        stride: 2
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "relu1"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
}

layer {
    name: "norm1"
    type: "LRN"
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "norm1"
    lrn_param {
        local_size: 3
        alpha: 0.00005
        beta: 0.75
        norm_region: WITHIN_CHANNEL
    }
}

layer {
    name: "pool1"
    type: "Pooling"
    bottom: "norm1"
    top: "pool1"
    pooling_param {
        kernel_size: 3
        stride: 2
        pad: 1
        pool: MAX
    }
}

layer {
    name: "conv2"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "pool1"
    top: "conv2"
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 256
        kernel_size: 5
        pad: 2
        stride: 2
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 1
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "relu2"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv2"
    top: "conv2"
}

layer {
    name: "norm2"
    type: "LRN"
    bottom: "conv2"
    top: "norm2"
    lrn_param {
        local_size: 3
        alpha: 0.00005
        beta: 0.75
        norm_region: WITHIN_CHANNEL
    }
}

layer {
    name: "pool2"
    type: "Pooling"
    bottom: "norm2"
    top: "pool2"
    pooling_param {
        kernel_size: 3
        stride: 2
        pad: 1
        pool: MAX
    }
}

layer {
    name: "conv3"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "pool2"
    top: "conv3"
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 384
        kernel_size: 3
        pad: 1
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "relu3"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv3"
    top: "conv3"
}

layer {
    name: "conv4"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "conv3"
    top: "conv4"
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 384
        kernel_size: 3
        pad: 1
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 1
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "relu4"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv4"
    top: "conv4"
}

layer {
    name: "conv5"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "conv4"
    top: "conv5"
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 0.0
    }
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 256
        kernel_size: 3
        pad: 1
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 1
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "relu5"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv5"
    top: "conv5"
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv5"
    bottom: "rois"
    top: "pool5"
    name: "roi_pool5"
    type: "ROIPooling"
    roi_pooling_param {
        pooled_w: 6
        pooled_h: 6
        spatial_scale: 0.0625  # (1/16)
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "pool5"
    top: "fc6"
    name: "fc6"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
    }
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 4096
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc6"
    top: "fc6"
    name: "relu6"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc6"
    top: "fc6"
    name: "drop6"
    type: "Dropout"
    dropout_param {
        dropout_ratio: 0.5
        scale_train: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc6"
    top: "fc7"
    name: "fc7"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
    }
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 4096
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "fc7"
    name: "relu7"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "fc7"
    name: "drop7"
    type: "Dropout"
    dropout_param {
        dropout_ratio: 0.5
        scale_train: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "cls_score"
    name: "cls_score"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
    }
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 21
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "angle_pred"
    name: "angle_pred"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
    }
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 9
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.001
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "bbox_pred"
    name: "bbox_pred"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
    }
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 84
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.001
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}

layer {
    name: "loss"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "cls_score"
    bottom: "labels"
    top: "loss_cls"
    loss_weight: 0
}

layer {
    name: "accuarcy"
    type: "Accuracy"
    bottom: "cls_score"
    bottom: "labels"
    top: "accuarcy"
}

layer {
    name: "loss_angle"
    type: "SmoothL1Loss"
    bottom: "angle_pred"
    bottom: "angle_head"
    bottom: "angle_head_weight"
    top: "loss_angle"
    loss_weight: 1
}

layer {
    name: "loss_bbox"
    type: "SmoothL1Loss"
    bottom: "bbox_pred"
    bottom: "bbox_targets"
    bottom: "bbox_loss_weights"
    top: "loss_bbox"
    loss_weight: 0
}
```

`

Comment: In particular I am speaking about "angle_pred"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the file you have uploaded is the training prototxt file. You have used `SoftmaxWithLoss` layer. This layer will not give you the probabilities. Replace it with `SoftMax` layer during deployment to get the probability of each class.

Comment: Just to confirm by "deployment" you mean TEST ?

Comment: yeah.. test prototxt

Answer (score 0):

You have used softmax function in the output layer to convert the scores generated by the neural network model to probability. Now you need to consider the max probability and the class associated with the max probability is your answer. By the way what did you mean by that, softmax function has no effect? Softmax function will also give you a vector, instead of a single value. You can decide from the probabilities what is the final class predicted by your classifier.

Comment: I did mention in my problem statement,  "It outputs me a 9x1 vector for each object which is fine but the values inside are not probabilities" The values are ranging from -180 to some positive integer. Whereas, probabilities should oscillate between [0 1].

Comment: Please check your softmax implementation then. I guess there is some mistake because its not possible that softmax is returning you a vector of unbounded values. The values should be in between 0-1 because the expression of softmax function includes normalization.

Comment: Ok let me debug. Thanks anyways.